# Oracle scoring report view based on multiple complex queries

Tags: sql, database, oracle, view, reporting

I would like to build a reporting tool in an Oracle database that calculates a score based on the result of multiple fairly complex queries that work on different tables. All of these queries will give me a list of a specific ID if certain criteria match.

**Here's an example:**

Imagine that there would be three queries "Find all user IDs that live in Seattle", "Find all user IDs that bought a car during the last three months" and "Find all user IDs that moved within the US more than 3 times". Each of these queries would get a score for a user if the user ID is found for a query e.g. query 1 = 3 points, query 2 = 5 points, query 3 = 2 points. The end result should give a list of users and their IDs that have a match for at least one of the queries. The result set would be ordered by the sum of all scores descending. The result set should be up-to-date.

```
| user_id | points_lived_in_seattle | points_bought_car | points_moved | sum |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     123 |                       3 |                 0 |            2 |   5 |
|     456 |                       0 |                 3 |            0 |   3 |
|     789 |                       0 |                 0 |            2 |   2 |
```

What's the best way to achieve a reporting tool like this in Oracle? I was thinking to create a view for it but this would be very hard because there could be 20 or more queries that could be added to this in the near future. Also I am worried about the fact that the joins that combines all queries don't work correctly and cause an incorrect result set.

Another option I was thinking about was to create a materialized view for each of the queries and one view that just creates the scoring based on the other views.

How would you go go about solving this problem? What could be the performance impact on the database overall if one the queries is very slow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you thinking about materialized views? Test the queries in one statement and if they're quick enough then use them. If not, and you've checked your indexes, why not just insert the results into a table and then "select * from table order by sum desc"?

Comment: Isn't the reason for using a materialized view that you want to have an aggregate of your data by improving the query execution times? I thought it would precalculate expensive joins and aggregation operations prior to execution and store the results in a table. The data should be up-to-date. Just running once and inserting it into a table won't help. I'd need a view. How would you combine the queries  to the scoring view in SQL?

Comment: If you're got expensive joins and aggregation operations then load on the database isn't diminished by the materialized view but increased due to all the extra activity that goes on around it; though I admit the query time would be quicker. As I understand it as well if a single row changes in the table that the materialized view is on then the entire materialized view has to be re-synched. It's what I do with all our massive queries. We create 20-30 tables with group by's from multi-million row tables and insert the results into reference tables that  can then be queried in seconds.

Comment: If you want your report to take seconds and you've got large tables then it'll be difficult to do this with 20 joins if you're using tables, materialized views or a single view to get them all together.

Comment: Sounds like you did something similar to this before. Yeah, I'd have to deal with multi-million row tables as well. Not sure if I read this correctly but you create multiple views by running group by-queries and then have an aggregation table that you insert the data from these views? It would be great if you could clarify this a big more.

Comment: @ben - the entire view doesn't need to be refreshed if you have a materialized view log on the base table, and you define it to fast refresh. Though there are restrictions, of course.

Comment: @Alex Benjamin is talking about materialized views with group by's in them. Any change to the table should affect the entire table no? Benjamin, you've understood; though I don't know whether it would help you without a lot more information but I run multiple queries simultaneously to do the horrendous group by's and then place all the information into a nicely indexed reference table. The only way you're guaranteed to get the best option though is to try everything and see.

Comment: @Ben: Once you built multiple views with the queries you want to run how would you formulate the query in SQL for the aggregation view in my example? Each of the views would have a `user_id`.